# How to avoid memory leak in mvvm architecture in android

Tags: android

### CODE:

**MainActivityViewModelFactory.java** (**VIEW MODEL FACTORY**)

```
public class MainActivityViewModelFactory implements ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    private Activity context;

    public MainActivityViewModelFactory(Activity context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        return (T) new MainActivityViewModel(context);
    }
}
```

**MainActivityViewModel.java** (**VIEW MODEL**)

public class MainActivityViewModel extends ViewModel implements IntGoogleListData {

```
private Activity context;


public MainActivityViewModel() {
}

public MainActivityViewModel(Activity context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

}

**MainActivity.java** (**ACTIVITY CLASS**)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private MainActivityViewModel activityViewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         activityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this,new MainActivityViewModelFactory(this)).get(MainActivityViewModel.class);
    }
}
```

**QUESTION:**

1. Assuming the activity is running, now since i have a `context`
   reference in view model. suddenly if i close the activity. will it
   cause a memory leak.
2. If memory leak is caused, How to prevent it

---

**Extending the question** Suppose I pass the context in view model( obtained from android videwmodel). to another class and hold reference ----------- Can we avoid memory leackage there( or this is wrong to do)

```
private class MyClassThread {

        Context mContext;

        public MyClassThread (Context mContext) {
           this.mContext = mContext;
        }

    }
```

**Then I call this in view model:**

new MyClassThread (context);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need a context in your viewModel, why not do an AndroidViewModel?

```
class MainActivityViewModel(application : Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) { 
    val context = applicaton.applicationContext
    ...   
}
```

In your Main Activity:

```
mainActivityViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainActivityViewModel::class.java)
```

This way, you will not leak memory.

Comment: You can improve that even further by using the resources, context is mostly use to getString and similars. If by any reason the context compat is needed then thar can also be initialized in the constructor, by example for getting colors, so the field would be the color instead

Comment: I agree if that's all you're doing.  However, sometimes context is needed for other things.

Comment: What else? Sharedprefferences, you could either pass it as an argument or initialize it in the constructor. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @KristyWelsh .... Your answer solves my question( So i accept the answer ) ... but i have extended the question to few more lines can you help me clarify the doubt.

Comment: @Devrath, you should NEVER pass in the context to a view model.